# How can show <p> tag content in place of first row when my table has now rows(No filtered matched)

Tags: angularjs

I have jquery , angularjs Datatable based table.
When no filter matches then it shows empty rows with only table headers.
I have to show  p tag content below table header.
This table is in wordpress so may be css is not working as it should.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Program Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Some program Name</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p>No filters found</p>
<!-- This content should be shown below table header-->
```

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: Please show the exact table markup your browser uses when the `p` should be displayed.

Comment: `$("p").toggle($("table>tbody>tr").length===0)` - of course, your sample HTML doesn't have a tbody and looks like your header would be in the implied tbody, so would need to check for `.length===1` or maybe 2 if your sample is two rows for the header.

Comment: If you are using [tag:datatables] (unclear if you've used the generic term "Datatable" or mean jquery-datatables) then use that API to display "no results" option.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution for my own answer
I changed my ng-repeat

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in filtered= (products | inArray:selectedCountries:'Institute' | filter : searchtxt1 | filter : searchtxt2 | filter : searchtxt3 | filter : searchtxt4 | rangeFilter:'Fees':ui.min:ui.max) | limitTo: 5">
```

Also added tbody with ng-show

```
<tbody><tr><td style="text-align:center;" colspan="21" ng-show="filtered.length === 0" class="agamotto">Filters didn't matched ! Please try Other Filters</td></tbody>
```

SOLVED !

Comment: For future reference: next time, please use the correct tags - this is neither a [tag:jquery], [tag:html] nor [tag:jquery] solution.